# Installing LuaSQL on Windows without local MySQL-server

Tags: windows, lua, luarocks, luasql

I'm part of a project and trying to make sure that our Lua code can interact with a given MySQL-database which I only have remote access to.

This causes problems when trying to install LuaSQL (through luarocks), giving the following error message:

"Error: Could not find expected file mysql.h, or mysql.h for MYSQL -- you may have to install MYSQL in your system and/or pass MYSQL_DIR or MYSQL_INCDIR to the luarocks command. Example: luarocks install luasql-mysql MYSQL_DIR=/usr/local"

I tried attaching the hostname, "MYSQL_DIR"="MySQLHostName" without any success.

Worth noting is the absence of anything MySQL-related on my local system. Do I need to install something of that kind? I am obviously not interested in a local server.

Edit: After recommendation I installed MySQL locally, and tried to proceed. I then got one step further, but faced problems with the command line not interpreting 'cl'. Running CMD as admin solved that.

Current state: Still missing files for the installation, despite doing the local installation of MySQL. No longer missing "mysql.h" but rather "string.h" and "winsock32.h" which I have no clue what they are.

Comment: you can use odbc. it did not require any external deps on windows. you just need install odbc driver for mysql

Answer (score 0):

You need the MySQL libraries to build LuaSQL. You can get them by either installing *MySQL Community Server for Windows*, or; alternatively, downloading the ZIP packages, extracting it and browsing to the `include/` directory in the package.

The `include/` directory contains all inkers and headers etc. sources for MySQL. It is this directory's path that is to be passed for `MYSQL_INCDIR` argument.

Comment: Thank you for you response. Naturally more, unrelated, problems arise. The installation script requires "cl" to be in the PATH. I am unable to find cl.exe in my system unless I enter:

"C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\bin"

which I believe is related to an old Python project.

Putting that in the path just gives a different error message, saying "cannot open include file: 'string.h': No such file or directory.

Indeed I also cannot find that file when browsing my include-directory.

Comment: run something like `VC command prompt`. checkout VC menu in start menu.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to make out of your suggestion, you may have to dumb it down/extend the answer a bit more. I'm not very well versed when it comes to this.